# Метод Clone<T>: T Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, rtti

У родительского класса есть метод `clone`, но вызов этого метода, дочерними классами, не совсем мне нравится. Необходимость указания типа дженерика мне кажется можно как то заменить, или нельзя?

```
function Clone<T:class, constructor>:T;

function TMainEntity.Clone<T>: T;
var
  PropList : PPropList;
  i: integer;
  PropCount : integer;
  TmpVar:Variant;
begin
  Result:= nil;
  if (Self = nil) or (Self.ClassInfo = nil)
    then exit;

  Result:= T.Create;
  PropCount := GetPropList(Self.ClassInfo, PropList);
  try
  for i:=0 to propCount-1 do
  begin
    TmpVar:= GetPropValue(Self, PropList[i].Name, true);
    SetPropValue(Result, PropList[i].Name, TmpVar);
  end;
  except
    Result.free;
    Result:= nil;
  end;
end;
```

и пример вызова метода:

```
var
  Var1,Var2:TVar;

Var1:= Var2.Clone<TVar>;
```

Можно конечно у каждого класса переопределить метод `clone` явно подставив типы.

```
function TVar.Clone: TVar;
begin
  Result:= inherited Clone<TVar>;
end;
```

Но возможно есть что-то более изящное?

Comment: вам бы ограничения `T : consturctor` и (или) наследниками ограничить. Плюс что у вас произойдет если класс T не будет иметь нужного свойства, или тип свойства будет отличаться?

Comment: как вариант, у вас должен быть просто метод `Clone(): TMainEntity;` а результат надо явно приводить к виду  наследника при вызове метода. зы: не называйте классы `TVarClass` ибо `T...Class` используются для метаклассов а-ля `TFormClass = class of TForm`

Comment: хотя чутка запутано написано. Если у вас есть два класса наследника `TChildA, TChildB` тогда суть то метода для чего? вызывать `b := a.Clone<TChildB>` ? если так то дженерик-метод вполне хорошо. Поясните суть задачи на примерах дочерних классов

Comment: @teran Да, ограничение не помешает. Исключение произойдет конечно, подразумевается что метод будет использоваться объектами одного класса. Кастованием заниматься тоже не хочется, лучше уже тогда переопределить метод.

Comment: из примера я правильно понял, что клонирование всегда возвращает экземпляр своего класса? и нельзя запрашивать клон другого типа?  Если пример неудачный просто? и в примере должно быть `v1 : TVar1; v2 : TVar2;` ? В общем подход с дженирик-методом самый оптимальный тут будет, имхо.

Comment: главное при таком клонировании понимать, что копию вы получите для `value`-типов, референс-поля скопируют ссылку на объект, и клоны будут разделять один ресурс. После чего уничтожив один клон, второй останется с битой ссылкой. и утечка памяти у вас там там при эксепшене. Объект создан, а вы ему просто `nil` присваиваете.

Comment: @teran Да, Вы правильно поняли, клонирование возвращает экземпляр своего класа. Объекты содержат только `value` типы. Возможно заморочусь с ссылочными типами, опять же они будут только наследниками `TMainEntity`, по этому "глубокое" клонирование я думаю проблем не вызовет

Comment: тогда дженерик не в тему, конечно. Либо переопределяйте в наследнике (в базовом классе тоже дженерик не нужен просто приводите к нужному типу).  Либо приводите при вызове, писать `v2 := v1.Сlone() as TVar`; вполне нормально, не знаю, что вам не нравится в приведении типов.